# Why is my Visual Studio 2019 Project not Running?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Every time I press "start" to start the project, it wouldn't run the project. I searched the web, but I couldn't find anything. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that didn't work. I am trying to run a Python project in 3.9. Just an FYI, I have been able to run this project before. Now, it just suddenly stopped working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No error? No repro steps? No [mcve]?

Comment: Nothing. The only way to reproduce it is to press the "start" button. There was no errors

Comment: Start without Debugging? Can you Build it and run the output in Release Mode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I clicked on "Build" and pressed "release" and ran the project. Didn't work

Comment: Your Python script probably just runs and finishes! Open a C# Console App and try with that or follow these proper instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JeremyThompson it has to print something. I made an adding project to get better at addition.

Comment: Last comment, use Vs Code instead.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I fixed the problem. I just made a new project and pasted the code. Problem fixed.